# How can I add new property to my state element

Tags: reactjs, redux

If my state element is duplicated, I want to add a property named "quantity" and make it +1 in each click.

**Reducer**

```
case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
      const addedItem = state.cart.find(c => c.id === action.payload.id)

      if (addedItem) {
        return Object.assign({}, addedItem, {quantity: addedItem.quantity++})
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        cart:
          state.cart.findIndex((c) => c.id === action.payload.id) >= 0
            ? state.cart
            : [...state.cart, action.payload]
      };
```

**State**

```
cart: []
```

**UI**

```
addToCart(p) {
    this.props.actions.addToCart({quantity: 1, p});
  }



{products.map((p) => (
                <tr key={p.id}>
                  <th scope="row">{p.id}</th>
                  <td>{p.productName}</td>
                  <td>{p.quantityPerUnit}</td>
                  <td>{p.unitPrice}</td>
                  <td>{p.unitsInStock}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => this.addToCart(p)}
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                    >
                      Add To Cart
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
```

This is what I tried and failed. I successed preventing duplicate elements in the state but I can't add its quantity property.

For example, I added A item twice. I want to see that A item has gained quantity property and it is 2.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your reducer as:

```
case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
      const existingItem = state.cart.find(c => c.id === action.payload.id)
      const itemToAdd = existingItem ? {...existingItem, quantity: existingItem.quantity + 1} : action.payload;

      return {
        ...state,
        cart:
          [...(state.cart.filter((c) => c.id !== action.payload.id)), itemToAdd]
      };
```

and also update the `addToCart` function

```
addToCart(p) {
   this.props.actions.addToCart({...p, quantity: 1});
}
```

Comment: This one increases quantity number when I add any item to cart. I want each item has quantity property, and if I add same item twice, its quantity number should increase.

Comment: can you check with the modified `addToCard` function? With the original one, payload.id was always undefined

Comment: Thank you so much. After I modified addToCart it worked. I will study these codes.